# Laravel 7 wrongly decoded Post

Tags: php, laravel, rest, post, request

I have controller method called `verify` that receives POST request from payment operator. When I tested it with REST API client everything was fine. But when I use testing tool provided by payment operator, verification fails because of missing POST fields. This "testing tool" returns the body of response, so I've var-dumped `$_POST` at the beginning of `verify` method and I'm receiving something like this:

```
array(1) { ["--------------------------b074713ef462b368 Content-Disposition:_attachment;_name"]=> string(752) ""KWOTA" 25.00 --------------------------b074713ef462b368 Content-Disposition: attachment; name="ID_PLATNOSCI" 56222c65a8aa9ac511da699895e4d0d1 --------------------------b074713ef462b368 Content-Disposition: attachment; name="ID_ZAMOWIENIA" 31c34e44-148f-40e2-9711-530c3c37db97 --------------------------b074713ef462b368 Content-Disposition: attachment; name="STATUS" SUCCESS --------------------------b074713ef462b368 Content-Disposition: attachment; name="SEKRET" WnFudHBQb0FOQzBRVnp6L2hEbzVEQVpiMy9JWDdmOWE5SktpenlWVjVmRT0, --------------------------b074713ef462b368 Content-Disposition: attachment; name="HASH" 9b90f501e2279d7404496242f6fe83bbd87fc5be4390bf466dba4bb6639d4af7 --------------------------b074713ef462b368--" }
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: they are not wrogly decoded, but instead they are encrypted, that's why you can't read them... check your payment gateway documentation and you will see that you should have a private key which will be used buy the payment gateway api that you have installed, to decode those request coming from it (otherwise you couldn't know whether that request comes from your payment gateway or someone else)

Comment: I have private key but their documentation says that instead of decrypting data I need to create sha256 hash with this private key and compare it with the other one that should be available in POST. [Here](https://pastebin.com/5WgTV4Mk) fragment of their example integration script. I've also checked their WooCommerce plugin and there also is no decryption of POST data.

Comment: comparing the hash gives you authenticity, but not consistency, so the informations must be decrypted at some point... however i'm unable to find any kind of documentation with that code, which service are you using?

Comment: HotPay.pl PaySafeCard Payment. Here is [documentation](https://hotpay.pl/documentation_v3/tech_paysafecard.pdf) (only in Polish, but you can find example php script on page 7) and [here](https://hotpay.pl/plik_download/6_psc-platnosci) WooCommerce plugin.

Comment: please try dd(request()->all()); and then post here what it output and also your "verify" method

Comment: Verify method - https://pastebin.com/15DEwRp0
dd displays - https://pastebin.com/be54uRzr
You can easily see data I need in this dump i.e `name="SEKRET" WnFudHBQb0FOQzBRVnp6L2hEbzVEQVpiMy9JWDdmOWE5SktpenlWVjVmRT0` but I dont know why are they wrongly decoded.